# Why does it work when I call the method which is not static without an object

Tags: java

I was very surprised when I saw that it works. Please explain why

https://github.com/bethrobson/Head-First-Java/blob/master/chap12/MiniMusicPlayer3.java

```
public void setUpGui() {  //  <------- it is not static
    ml = new MyDrawPanel();
    f.setContentPane(ml);
    f.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void go() {    
    setUpGui();  //  <---  call without object.setUpGui() !!!
```

Why does it work?

Comment: Whatya talking about Willis?  `MiniMusicPlayer3 mini = new MiniMusicPlayer3();        mini.go();`  - it is already instantiated

Answer (score 6):

The call to the nonstatic method setUpGui() is performed from a nonstatic method go().

At the time when go() is running, there must be an instance of the surrounding class MiniMusicPlayer3, and it is accessible via 'this'. When execution shifts from go() to setUpGui() this context is still valid.

The object was created when calling the constructor prior to calling the go() method.

Answer (score 4):

The `setUpGui` method is implicitly called on the `this` object. In this particular case, that's `mini`.

Answer (score -2):

`setUpGui` and `go` methods are both inside the same class, In the same class you need not to instantiate the object, until you are calling it from the static method. Like when you called the `go` method inside the `main` method, your `go` method is not static so you created the `mini` object and called the `go` method. But `go` method is not static so you can call `setUpGui` method directly without creating object.